# html rendering time improvement with jquery datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables, rendering

I had implemented datatable with almost 3000 row of data and it was taking like 4 to 5 seconds to render the HTML by this code:

```
$('#book_table').html(book_table);
$('#book_table > table').DataTable({...data table initializing});
```

when I was trying to improve rendering time I tried to hide the HTML data container element (display: none) then show it after datatable initializing and the result was shocked it took just 200 ms for rendering by this code

```
$('#book_table').addClass('hidden');
$('#book_table').html(book_table);
$('#book_table > table').DataTable({...data table initializing});
$('#book_table').removeClass('hidden');
```

the question is : **how could hiding the data container and showing it after datatable initializing could improve the rendering time from 4 seconds to 200 ms?**

Comment: It's likely because internally DataTables is appending a row at a time (ie. at least one DOM operation per row, probably more than that in actuality) which is slow. Hiding the table means that the UI does not need to be redrawn while the amendment is made, hence it's faster. I'd question why you need to show 3000 records though. I'd suggest using filter/paging to only show relevant data to your user

Comment: thanks for your explanation it makes sense.

Comment: actully they i am using the pagination for 100 row for each page by this code: 
**lengthMenu: [ [100, 200, -1], [100, 200, "Tüm Kayıtlar"] ],
language: datatables_tr_options,
bFilter: false,
bLengthChange: false,
responsive: true,
dom: 'Bfrtip',
buttons: [
{
 extend: 'excelHtml5',
    exportOptions: {
        columns: [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 13 ]
    }
}
]**
but for some reason it was taking 4 seconds before the hiding/showing data container

Comment: In that case I assume you're adding the 3000 records directly in the source, and not loading them on a per-page basis from the server.

Comment: You are not get Rory message. What u did is looping all db to html table, instead using ajax which only looping 10 rows per request (by default). U maybe just look 10 rows too (in your current script). but when you see your source you will know if u force to show 3000 rows, not 10 rows. `view-source:https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/dom.html` you will see 57 rows in page source, but in `view-source:https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/simple.html` you not see any (even 1) rows. cz data is return from ajax. If you using ajax, you will no need answer for this question